# more efficiently read int values from console

Tags: java, input, user-input

How can I read int values from console more efficiently (from memory) than this:

```
BufferedReader in ...
number = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
```

When I use `readLine()` and parse it to int, java create many String objects and сonsumes memory. I try to use `Scanner` and method `nextInt()` but this approach is also not that efficiently.

> P.S I need read > 1000_000 values and I have memory limit.

**EDIT** Full code of task

```
import java.io.*;

public class Duplicate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int last = 0;
        boolean b = false;

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int number =Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            if (number == 0 && !b) {
                System.out.println(0);
                b = true;
            }
            if (number == last) continue;
            last = number;
            System.out.print(last);
        }
    }
}
```

And Rewrite variant:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

public class Duplicate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int last = 0;
        boolean b = false;

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int nextInt = getNextInt(reader);

        for (int i = 0; i < nextInt; i++) {
            int number = getNextInt(reader);
            if (number == 0 && !b) {
                System.out.println(0);
                b = true;
            }
            if (number == last) continue;
            b = true;
            last = number;
            System.out.println(last);
        }
    }

    static int getNextInt(Reader in) throws IOException {
        int c;
        boolean negative = false;
        do {
            c = in.read();
            if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
                negative = c == '-';
            }
        } while (c != -1 && !Character.isDigit(c));
        if (c == -1) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        int num = Character.getNumericValue(c);
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1 && Character.isDigit(c)) {
            num = 10 * num + Character.getNumericValue(c);
        }
        return negative ? -num : num;
    }
}
```

Both options do not pass from memory (((

[image]

**EDIT2** I try profiling

i`nt number = getRandom();` and start with 1000000

[image]

once again launched the same
[image]

and splash GC

[image]

Comment: Yes, it will create a lot of strings - but those strings will immediately be eligible for garbage collection. Is this a theoretical concern or are you actually running out of memory, and do you have evidence that the problem is due to a lot of strings?

Comment: I have a limit of 20mb. My program on the 193th test does not work in the system as it starts to consume more memory

Comment: Oracle Java 8 ML(Memory limit) 0.783s 21.87Mb 193(test number)

Comment: Then you have a memory leak. Show code. Do you know how to use a profiler like visualvm?

Comment: I solve the problem on a specialized site. I write the code and send it there. as a result, the code either passes or does not. I do not have that set of tests that are used on this site

Comment: You could still try running the code locally with a profiler though. Additionally, it would be worth providing all this information within the question itself.

Comment: How do you store this 1_000_000 integers? Or do you process them one by one? Maybe problem is not in Scanner.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I try profilling and eddit question

Answer (score 1):

You can read from `in` one char at a time, checking if it's a digit, and then accumulating it into a number. Something like:

```
int getNextInt(Reader in) throws IOException {
  int c;
  boolean negative = false;
  do {
    c = in.read();
    if (!Character.isDigit(c)) { negative = c == '-' };
  } while (c != -1 && !Character.isDigit(c));
  if (c == -1) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;  // Some sentinel to indicate nothing found.

  int num = Character.getNumericValue(c);
  while ((c = in.read()) != -1 && Character.isDigit(c)) {
    num = 10 * num + Character.getNumericValue(c);
  }
  return negative ? -num : num;
}
```

[Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/k8vHOT)

Of course, this is incredibly primitive parsing. But you could perhaps take this code as a basis and adapt it as required.

Comment: This is similar to what I need. It remains to solve the issue with negative values) thanks. I will write how I decide and report the result.

Comment: With your help, I got the same result ((((This was the last option that I assumed. I ran out of patience. I would add the code for the whole task to the question, I would be happy if you look and you can see what else can affect the lack of memory

Comment: There isn't any new memory being allocated in the code. Pretty much the only extraneous stuff is the `BufferedReader` and the `InputStreamReader`: you could read bytes directly from the stream, assuming it will contain no non ASCII characters; but I struggle to see that making a meaningful difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `FastScanner` class

```
static class FastScanner {
    private BufferedReader reader = null;
    private StringTokenizer tokenizer = null;

    public FastScanner(InputStream in) {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        tokenizer = null;
    }

    public String next() {
        if (tokenizer == null || !tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            try {
                tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return tokenizer.nextToken();
    }

    public String nextLine() {
        if (tokenizer == null || !tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            try {
                return reader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        return tokenizer.nextToken("\n");
    }

    public long nextLong() {
        return Long.parseLong(next());
    }

    public int nextInt() {
        return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }
}
```

It is very commonly used on `codeforces` to read large input where `Scanner` class leads to `TLE`

This is originally authored by https://codeforces.com/profile/Petr

Comment: If you're going to use this, why wouldn't you just use a `StringTokenizer`? And since you're calling `reader.readLine()`, why wouldn't you just parse that, as in OP's code?

Comment: Why recommending code containing StringTokenizer? how many versions of Java has it been deprecated now?

Comment: I was not aware that `StringTokenizer` is deprecated.. Thanks @Stultuske

Comment: But it serves the purpose for now. It can be refactored to use `split()` as per the documentation. I will do that later

Answer (score 0):

I use this InputReader on `codeforces`. Works pretty well for me on large input cases. You can extend this up to your use case. I came across this after getting `TLE` using `Scanner` and add functionalities if needed.

```
static class InputReader {
    private final InputStream stream;
    private final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    private int curChar;
    private int numChars;

    public InputReader(InputStream stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    private int read() {
        try {
            if (curChar >= numChars) {
                curChar = 0;
                numChars = stream.read(buf);
                if (numChars <= 0)
                    return -1;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return buf[curChar++];
    }

    public int readInt() {
        return (int) readLong();
    }

    public long readLong() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c)) {
            c = read();
            if (c == -1) throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        boolean negative = false;
        if (c == '-') {
            negative = true;
            c = read();
        }
        long res = 0;
        do {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9') throw new InputMismatchException();
            res *= 10;
            res += (c - '0');
            c = read();
        } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
        return negative ? (-res) : (res);
    }

    public int[] readIntArray(int size) {
        int[] arr = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) arr[i] = readInt();
        return arr;
    }

    private boolean isSpaceChar(int c) {
        return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\t' || c == -1;
    }

}
```